# How to hide a frame from a child of another frame?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

How can I hide a frame from the content of another one. I mean:

```
Parent
 Frame F1
   Page P1
 Frame F2
   Page P2
```

I want from P2 hide the frame F1 using Javascript of JQuery.

Comment: Do you mean how do you access F1 from the JS within P2?

Comment: yes, and I want to hide not access it only

Comment: Are all these frames from the same domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

**iframe-access.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="iframe1.html" id="iframe1"></iframe>
<iframe src="iframe2.html" id="iframe2"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**iframe1.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Iframe 1</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**iframe2.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('Hide Iframe 1');
window.parent.document.getElementById('iframe1').style.display = 'none';
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Iframe 2</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jfcoder.com/test/iframe-access.html

**NOTE**

This will also work (as Jose points out):

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('framesetID').rows = "0%,*";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. the content is cleared but the frame itslelf is not hidden.

Comment: what happened is the area of the frame becomes gray, that is all.

Comment: Can you add what you have to your answer? If it's working, the iframe is set to `display: none`. You're not using `visibility: hidden`, are you?

Comment: Thanks, I've used: `window.parent.document.getElementById('framesetID').rows = "0%,*";` and it works well.

Comment: @Jose - Good deal, I'll add it to my answer.